# Loading Facebook in a WebView, behaves weird

Tags: android, android-webview, android-viewpager, webviewclient

I'm loading ***m.facebook.com*** in my WebView, not sure how important that is, but the webview is in a container within a ViewPager.

Every time I launch the application and load the url I see one of the following results:

**One which you would actually expect:**

[image]

**But the other is quite disturbing:**

[image]

Why are these two behaviors?

The XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/Site_WebView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The setup code for the WebView:

```
webView.loadUrl(item.getUrl());
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setUserAgentString("My User Agent - Android");
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {});
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {});
```

I inflate the xml in the adapter, and add it to the container...

Comment: Can you post the code generating the content you're seeing?  And any XML governing the layout?

Comment: There is really nothing to it... it seem for me like a simple inflation of a layout, putting it a viewpager, and then it happens, once or twice normal the other times, weird behavior:/

Comment: I'm not touching any CSS, or inject any sort of Javascript, the only thing I can think of is a race condition between the page layout invalidator, and the page renderer threads, and I don't know why!

Comment: I've added a check and printed the windows width, using Javascript, and it states the correct size 800x1080... so I keep on wondering what the hell is going on?

Comment: Can you post a sscce?  I'd like to look at this too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After understanding this is not a race condition between the ViewPager, and the drawer, I've dug into the page, t find out that Facebook customize the page width according to some parameters which I cared not about...

Later I've installed user agent switcher extension to Chrome, and been able to reproduce it, with a my custom user agent.

I did not expect the user agent to have such an effect on a page...

But hell, I've been wrong a billion times before!

Answer (score 2):

After breaking my head all testing here, I found out that it is the 'user agent'. The m.facebook.com.br change the html / css code as the user agent that spent for it.

Remove this line in your code: 
settings.setUserAgentString ("My Agent - Android");

And everything will work.

Comment: Thank you for the answer... I need to expand this question as that is not the only weird behavior I've seen with Facebook and mobile apps...

I'll do this shortly...